# Is it okay to put my temporary files into a tmp/ directory in my app?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have a Django Application in Cloud Run that has a method of creating temporary files. Since it is in Cloud Run, the files may disappear since it is a "stateless" container.

So I tried to upload the temporary files to Google Cloud Storage, but it makes the app too slow. I have read about this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files and it says about creating temporary files to a tmp/ directory using Python3 methods. I was wondering where to create this "tmp/" directory.

Do I need to store the tmp/ directory just in my root directory of my Application or do I need to make a tmp/ directory to Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Cloud Run container contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#filesystem), the entire filesystem is writable.  It's also stored entirely in memory, so **any files you write will occupy memory**.  It's customary on unix to use /tmp as a temporary folder, but if the entire filesystem is writable, I imagine you can choose whatever you want.

Cloud Run is not at all related to Cloud Storage with respect to the files written locally.